Migratiing Content Delivery API from Optimizely 11 to 12
We are currently migrating from Optimizely 11 to Optimizely 12, with a focus on the Content Delivery API. During this migration, I have addressed a number of breaking changes as detailed in the documentation: Breaking Changes.
One notable difference in the API response is the expansion of items. I followed the instructions provided here: Customizing Conversion, but the expanded items are still coming back as null.
I reached out to Optimizely support, and they provided a sample code which I used, but the expanded items remain null.
Here's the sample code provided by Optimizely
using System;
using EPiServer.ContentApi.Core.Serialization;
using EPiServer.ContentApi.Core.Serialization.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Foundation.Features.Api
{
 public class ExpandContentApiModelFilter : IContentApiModelFilter
 {
     private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
     private const string ExpandingScopeKey = "ContentDeliveryApi:ExpandingScope";
     private const int MaxExpandLevel = 3;

     public ExpandContentApiModelFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
     {
         _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
     }

     public Type HandledContentApiModel => typeof(ContentApiModel);

     public void Filter(ContentApiModel contentApiModel, ConverterContext converterContext)
     {
         foreach (var property in contentApiModel.Properties.Values)
         {
             if (property is ContentAreaPropertyModel contentArea)
             {
                 using (new ExpandingScope(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext))
                 {
                     if (GetExpandingLevel(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext) > MaxExpandLevel)
                     {
                         return;
                     }

                     if (contentArea.ExpandedValue is null)
                     {
                         contentArea.Expand(converterContext.Language);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     private static int GetExpandingLevel(HttpContext context)
     {
         if (context.Items.TryGetValue(ExpandingScopeKey, out var value) && value is ExpandingContext expandingContext)
         {
             return expandingContext.Level;
         }

         return 0;
     }

     private class ExpandingContext
     {
         public int Level { get; set; } = 0;
     }

     private class ExpandingScope : IDisposable
     {
         private readonly HttpContext _requestContext;

         public ExpandingScope(HttpContext context)
         {
             _requestContext = context;
             if (context.Items.TryGetValue(ExpandingScopeKey, out var value) && value is ExpandingContext expandingContext)
             {
                 expandingContext.Level++;
             }
             else
             {
                 context.Items[ExpandingScopeKey] = new ExpandingContext();
             }
         }

         public void Dispose()
         {
             if (_requestContext.Items[ExpandingScopeKey] is ExpandingContext currentContext)
             {
                 if (currentContext.Level > 0)
                 {
                     currentContext.Level--;
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 throw new InvalidOperationException();
             }
         }
     }
 }
}


Below code is added as part of configureservices in startup.cs
            services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IContentApiModelFilter, ExpandContentApiModelFilter>());


Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have suggestions on what might be missing?
Any input would be greatly appreciated.
